# NavigationController is not popping the Pushed View on Back button

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Having a simple Navigation Controller in place (starting the Navigation Based Application project) I created a new View with a XIB file.

on my `HomeViewController` (Home screen with all options as `UIButton`'s I have:

```
@implementation HomeViewController

-(IBAction) optionChoosed:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button: %d", button.tag];
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hi" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Go away" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    
    switch (button.tag) {
        case 13:
            // Simple Search
            [self loadSimpleSearch]; break;
            
        default:
            [alert show];           
            break;
    }
    [alert release];
}

-(void)loadSimpleSearch
{
    SimpleSearchViewController *controller = 
        [[SimpleSearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SimpleSearchViewController" bundle:nil];
    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

witch works great!

it Pushes the View into the front of the stack!

Now, because in my 2nd view `SimpleSearchViewController` I have `self.title = @"myTitle";` I get the Title in the NavigationBar as well the back button (as I have the same setting on the `HomeViewController`)

I thought that the NavigationViewController would handle the pop of the current view, but it does not.

> **What do I have to do**, to pop the `SimpleSearchViewController`?
>
> **Where do I use** `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

as the view continues there, and `ViewDidUnload` is never called.

My idea was that this should be handle in the first ViewController, the `HomeViewController` but I have no idea what is the method I should hook to, and I read the documentation and I can't figure it out :-/

Any help is greatly appreciated, **thank you**.

`HomeViewController`

[alt text http://cl.ly/XNS/Screen_shot_2010-04-21_at_22.38.51.png](http://cl.ly/XNS/Screen_shot_2010-04-21_at_22.38.51.png)

`SimpleSearchViewController`

[alt text http://cl.ly/YDw/Screen_shot_2010-04-21_at_22.40.00.png](http://cl.ly/YDw/Screen_shot_2010-04-21_at_22.40.00.png)

`SimpleSearchViewController` after pressing the *Back* button

[alt text http://cl.ly/XLO/Screen_shot_2010-04-21_at_22.40.21.png](http://cl.ly/XLO/Screen_shot_2010-04-21_at_22.40.21.png)

---

To add the image from a comment that asks if HomeViewController as the root controller for the NavigationViewController

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code of the SimpleSearchViewController where you set the title ?
Are you placing the back button yourself ?

Comment: No I'm not, this is automatically, all you need to do is set the title in the ViewDidLoad event `self.title = @"Home";`

Comment: Did you set the HomeViewController as the root controller for the NavigationViewController ?

Comment: yes, it is the root as you can see by the image http://cl.ly/ZFa or am I wrong :-(

Comment: @Sebastian Roth I moved this project to use Web and PhoneGap instead :( - though I'm a C# developer, ObjC is kinda weird still, and I had a "time stamp" on this project so I went for web instead.

Comment: Yeah it is kinda weird. In fact I had the same problem like you, and or some child controller this is working, (dealloc called) while for others it isn't. But I learned a key issue today: `viewWillDisappear` is a good helper. :-)

Comment: add an answer with the solution, I will set as correct and it will help other in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps but when implementing navigationItem in code, if you don't call the super the popping functionality will not be present

```
-(UINavigationItem*) navigationItem
{
    UINavigationItem* item = [super navigationItem];
    item.title = @"search";
    return item;
}
```